# Solr, multivalued field: how can I return documents where ALL values in the field are contained within a set?

Tags: solr

For example, if I have these 2 Documents:

```
id: 1
multifield: 2, 5

id: 2
multifield: 2, 5, 9
```

Then say I have a **set** that I'm querying with, which is {2, 5, 7}.  What I would want is document 1 returned because 2 and 5 are both contained in the set.  But document 2 should not be returned because 9 is not in the set.

Both the multivalued field and my set are of arbitrary length. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured this out.   [This](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Reverse-range-query-td1789135.html) was the inspiration, specifically the answer suggesting to use [Function Queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery).

Using the same data in the question, I will add a calculated field to my documents which contains the number of values in my multivalued field.

```
id: 1
multifield: 2, 5
nummultifield: 2

id: 2
multifield: 2, 5, 9
nummultifield: 3
```

Then I'll use an frange with some function queries.  For each item in my set, I'll use the termfreq function which will return 1 or 0.  I will then sum up all of these values.  Finally, if that sum equals the calculated field nummultifield, then I know that for that document, every value in the document is present in the set. Remember my set is 2,5,7 so my function query will look something like this:

```
fq={!frange l=0 u=0}sub( nummultifield, sum( termfreq(multifield,2), termfreq(multifield,5), termfreq(multifield,7)))
```

If we fill in the values for Document 1 and 2, it will look like this:

```
Document 1:  sub( 2, sum( 1,1,0 ) ) = 0  ' in my range of {0,0} so Doc 1 is returned
Document 2:  sub( 3, sum( 1,1,0 ) ) = 1  ' not in the range of {0,0} so not returned
```

I've tested it out and it works great.  You need to make sure you don't duplicate any values in multifield or you'll get weird results.  Incidentally, this trick of using frange could be used whenever you want to fake a boolean result from one or more function queries.

Comment: How did you get the dynamic field to return the number of values you have in the multivalue field?

Comment: Not a dynamic field, it's maintained manually.  Ugly but effective

Comment: This is what I ended up going with. It works nicely so all good :)

Answer (score 0):

Faceting may be the what you are looking for.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview

http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/technical-articles/faceted-search-solr

[how to search for more than one facet in solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065146/how-to-search-for-more-than-one-facet-in-solr/8065330#8065330)

---

I adapted this from the Lucid Imagination link.

Choose all documents that have values 2 or 5 or 7:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*
  &facet=on
  &facet.field=multifield
  &fq=multifield:2
  &fq=multifield:5
  &fq=multifield:7
```

---

**Incomplete**: I dont know any options to **exclude** all other values.

Comment: I don't think this works.  fq=multifield:7 would cause document 1 to be filtered since all fq's are AND'd

Comment: Did you try it? Im away from my office PC for a while, but I am pretty sure it means **set union**, "return all rows whose *multifield* takes values either *2* or *5* or *7*", which is an OR operation. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm very sure that the fq's are all AND'd together.  See this for a feature request (feel free to vote for it!) I submitted to Solr to give more options: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1223?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13148341#comment-13148341

Comment: Then check out the third link I mentioned in this answer for Boolean filters - I never tried it myself. Wish I had my code to double-check my approach.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I don't see how that will help.  Remember, I'm really doing a "reverse query" here, ALL of the values in the document must be present in the set I'm using to search.  See my answer below, I think that should work.